# MVC3 how do you specify a path to image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

the image is located under: /Content/panoramic/panoramas/UCCParc.tif

I access the image like:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/panoramic/panoramas/" + @imgName + "")"/>
```

But when I try to load the page localhost/pano, where pano is a controller, the images are not found. Is this the correct way of acessing the file in MVC3? Is it correct to specify the folder hierarchi as the path to the image or should I somehow wrap a controller around the path?

Comment: What is the path that is being generated by Url.Content()?

Comment: /Content/panoramic/panoramas/img1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code is fine but the best way to find the problem is using "Inspect Element" or other tools (Bugs in Firefox) to find out the correct URL that generated by your code. (Right-Click on images space and select 'Inspect Element' and see if the path to image is correct or not).

Comment: I did that. the url is ok but I think when the browser send the request to get the image from /Content/panoramic/panoramas/img1.jpg  mvc3 looks for a controller called Content/ and so on...